# Ubuntu 22.04 External monitor not detected

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 22.04, display, hdmi

I have recently install 22.04 Ubuntu OS and I lost external monitor connectivity. I have tried few things but stuck.

MSI Laptop with LG monitor
intel + nvidia
OS: Ubuntu 22.04

**xrandr**:

```
HDMI-1-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x202
    Timestamp:  18422
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      4 5 6 7
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    PRIME Synchronization: 1 
        supported: 0, 1
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: TMDS 
        supported: TMDS
    ConnectorType: HDMI 
    ConnectorNumber: 0 
    _ConnectorLocation: 0 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
```

I turn off *wayland* setting and turn on *X11* And whenever I go to *Settings > About* my laptop freeze.

Additionally, I don't see display layout to setup monitor. I have Dell Dock and tried with DP1 and HDMI cables but didn't work.

I tried all possible solution, purge and install nvidia drivers, ubuntu-drivers autoinstall, OS re-install with safe graphics.

[image]

Appreciate your time.

**EDIT**

I have multiple drivers from the Additional driver window. I tried green highlighted drivers.

[image]

**What I did?**

- Select drivers and install it. Click on restart now button.
- After restart, open a terminal and run command `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. Afterwards, reboot.
- Go to Settings > Display. No effect. Same window as previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried multiple tricks to find a solution inside the Linux system. Afterwards, I have tried to find a solution for the Dock driver connector to display my external monitor. And it works, here what I have done:

- Download external Nvidia drivers as mentioned by kepler-22. https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx
- Go to terminal and run downloaded file from above link: `sudo ./filename.run` In my case, I did `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.85.05.run`
- Download Ubuntu drivers for Dell Dock from https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu
- Open downloaded folder. It has a .run file. In my case, `sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.6.1-59.184.run`
- sudo reboot
- Additionally, I had to install `sudo apt-get install evdi-dkms`
- Afterwards, I got an external display (LG), Dell Dock with MSI laptop.

Answer (score 2):

You should try with different Nvidia driver versions (for me 510 worked but 525 didn't). For me, the Nvidia website .run file installer worked perfectly.

I can't help you unfreeze your desktop, but you may want to keep an eye on whether the CPUs work at 100%. If that's the case, I would rather reinstall the driver and purge all Nvidia (you have to  do it correctly depending on how you installed it (proprietary run file (my case), Ubuntu software&updates or apt), I would rather avoid gpg keys + .deb install since it didn't work even once for me because something-something deprecated, when purging Nvidia you may want to sudo apt autoremove *Nvidia* instead of remove... It might also help to fix software&updates if it gets struk with "using proprietary driver", also if something refuses to work no matter what you might want to check it is not blacklisted, never erase folders (I did, and it didn't end well) there's always an official way to uninstall it (unless you download random stuff from GitHub (this is unrelated, but, trust me, you may want to check there's a proper uninstall method when using a GitHub project, and you certainly want to keep it away from touching your packages without using apt)).

You may want to enable the different configuration for each xdisplay in the driver settings (once you get it working) it does the trick sometimes (I broke my system tinkering and I had to redo this a few times).

You might want to ensure that the password menu loads on your main screen (because if it doesn't you might not be able to enter the desktop other than recovery mode root when you're away from the hdmi)

> This I solved by deleting the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file. Yet you may want to try a better alternative since for me this made X11 think I had one screen, and even though both worked fine, there was a noticeable traffic through the CPU (non threaded) thus a very strong bottleneck for the system. This can be fixed by using Wayland

My system is and CPU with integrated graphics and Nvidia, thus my iGPU/GPU switching might work different from yours.

You can also try making Nvidia generate the xorg.conf file. And it might interest you to tinker with /etc/default/grub ... sudo dmesg might provide you more hints to browse the web or an "expert for them to help you.

Comment: I tried most of combination but didn't work. My OS kernel version is `5.15.0-58-generic`. May I know what is yours kernel? And I verified `/etc/X11` folder, I don't have file as you mentioned. I have something `xorg.conf.d` folder but it's empty.

Comment: I use Xanmod kernel stable release for Ubuntu 22.04 (needed it to fix some Bluetooth kernel issues) As for the Nvidia driver, I installed it from here: https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx

Comment: Very helpful. I switched to using 510 from 525 and got the monitor working. Nothing else worked.

Answer (score 2):

On my side, I just had to change the driver to the recommended (and tested) driver from Software & Updates and everything worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I installed the latest nvidia drivers i.e. `nvidia-driver-545` and I got my display back again.