# Can't install NVIDIA Driver Ubuntu 22.04 successfully - nvidia-smi and External Monitor notworking

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04

My Env:

Dell G5
Ubuntu 22.04
NVIDIA RTX2070 mobile

I've read many posts about this and tried most solutions.

A recap of what I did:

- Installed many drivers
- Tried auto install
- had this problem: [ubuntu-drivers "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment" when installing nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436601/ubuntu-drivers-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-version-referenced-before-as) but didn't want to change my python packages so avoided the solution in the thread
- tried to download nvidia&displaylink driver according to [Ubuntu 22.04 External monitor not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451002/ubuntu-22-04-external-monitor-not-detected)

That pretty much sums it up.

Would appreciate it if someone could help me get NVIDIA working properly (detection of a monitor and nvidia-smi working)

Comment: Which driver are you installing?  Avoid the ones with names ending in "-open" as those might cause a parse error looking for the version.  Clean out every package with nvidia in the name, and start again.

Comment: Can you give us more context and history? The more things you've been trying, the more details you need to provide to describe the situation. The appropriate proprietary driver should have already been installed when you originally installed Ubuntu. Was it not? Trying to unsuccessfully install driver after driver after driver can create situations where even if you do the right things in the future, you've created problems that prevent it from working. Unfortunately, if you've been hacking away at this, it may be difficult to clean up. Please edit your question with more details.